# SQL - Missing right parenthesis error

Tags: mysql-error-1064, mysql-error-1005

SQL Code

```
    SELECT DtsDavaIslem.DAVAISLEM_NO, DtsDavaIslem.DOSYA_ID, DtsDavaIslem.ISEMRI_NO, 
    DtsDavaIslem.GIREN_KULLANICI, DtsDavaIslem.GIRIS_TARIHI, DtsDavaIslem.DEGISTIREN_KULLANICI, 
    DtsDavaIslem.DEGISTIRME_TARIHI, DtsDavaIslem.ISLEMLISTESINO, DtsDavaIslem.YAPILACAKIS, 
    DtsDavaIslem.BASLANGICTARIHI, dtsdavaislem.bitmesigerekentarih, (SELECT 
DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEM_ADI || ';' || DtsDavaIslem.ISLEMLISTESINO FROM DTS.DAVA_ISLEMLISTESI                   DtsDavaIslemListesi WHERE 
    DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEMLISTESINO=DtsDavaIslem.ISLEMLISTESINO ) AS islem_auto_suggest FROM DTS.DAVA_ISLEM DtsDavaIslem WHERE 1=1
```

Do you edit the SQL code for me please?

```
Error


oracle.jbo.SQLStmtException: JBO-27122: Deyim haz?rl??? s?ras?nda SQL hatas? olu?tu. Deyim: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEMLISTESINO,
  DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEM_ADI,
  DtsDavaIslemListesi.GIREN_KULLANICI,
  DtsDavaIslemListesi.GIRIS_TARIHI,
  DtsDavaIslemListesi.DEGISTIREN_KULLANICI,
  DtsDavaIslemListesi.DEGISTIRME_TARIHI,
  DtsDavaIslemListesi.dava_durumno,
  DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEM_ADI || ';' ||    DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEMLISTESINO as Aciklama
FROM dts.dava_islemlistesi dtsdavaislemlistesi
WHERE :bSorgu<>'1'
AND 1=1) QRSLT  WHERE ( ( (ACIKLAMA = :vc_temp_1 ) ) )

ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Do you edit the SQL code for me please?
```

Comment: Your code starts with: "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT", is that correct? And if so, why does it start that way?

Comment: My code starts with "SELECT DtsDavaIslem.DAVAISLEM_NO,DtsDavaIslem.DOSYA_ID, DtsDavaIslem.ISEMRI_NO" bla bla...

Comment: If so is the case then you got one right parentheses to much. The one at "AND 1=1)" doesn't have any beginning if the case where that your code started with "SELECT DtsDav... bla bla"

Comment: Sql code SELECT DtsDavaIslem.DAVAISLEM_NO, DtsDavaIslem.DOSYA_ID, DtsDavaIslem.ISEMRI_NO, DtsDavaIslem.GIREN_KULLANICI, DtsDavaIslem.GIRIS_TARIHI, DtsDavaIslem.DEGISTIREN_KULLANICI, DtsDavaIslem.DEGISTIRME_TARIHI, DtsDavaIslem.ISLEMLISTESINO, DtsDavaIslem.YAPILACAKIS, DtsDavaIslem.BASLANGICTARIHI, dtsdavaislem.bitmesigerekentarih, (SELECT DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEM_ADI || ';' || DtsDavaIslem.ISLEMLISTESINO FROM DTS.DAVA_ISLEMLISTESI DtsDavaIslemListesi WHERE DtsDavaIslemListesi.ISLEMLISTESINO=DtsDavaIslem.ISLEMLISTESINO ) AS islem_auto_suggest FROM DTS.DAVA_ISLEM DtsDavaIslem WHERE 1=1

Comment: Why the useless WHERE 1=1 ? Why does the code in your answer and the code in your comment not match?

Comment: Because my code behind . I have a if in the java file.

            if (!qNewCondition.equals("1=1")) {
                int index = query.indexOf("1=1");
                newQuery = query.substring(0, index);
                newQuery = newQuery + qNewCondition;
                setQuery(newQuery);

            }

Comment: So you have a working query, you then modify it, and execute the modified query. Now you get an error. What use is it to say that the query *before* the modifications works? That's not the query you're executing. The query you're executing is what needs to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 left "(" and 3 right ")". They are called "parenthesis". If the error says missing right parenthesis, it means you're missing one or more ")". Next time first google it (or bing it :P) before asking such a question.

Answer (score 0):

The error isn't in the SQL from beginning but in the sql that your code is making up. So look at the sql before it executes and look where you went wrong.

If you look at the error you can se how the SQL is wrong, but you will need to look at your own code to find where you're building it up wrong.